# per-route message handler is resulting in 404 not found

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have got a very simple Web API message handler. When this message handler is applied globally, it just works fine. If I apply it per-route then my routes start failing with `404 Not Found` error. I have debugged it to the point where it is able to locate the controller correctly. A controller instance is successfully created but framework fails to find a qualifying action method to process my request. Here is my code for per-rout message handler configuration

```
public void RegisterRoutes(HttpConfiguration config)
{

    var handler = new AuthenticationHandler();
    var handlers = new DelegatingHandler[] {handler};

    var routeHandlers = HttpClientFactory.CreatePipeline(new HttpControllerDispatcher(config), handlers);
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApi", "api/{tenancy}/{controller}", null, null, routeHandlers);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have looks correct.

I usually code it like this:

```
 HttpMessageHandler AuthenticationHandler = HttpClientFactory.CreatePipeline(new HttpControllerDispatcher(config), new DelegatingHandler[] { new AuthenticationHandler() });
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(name: "DefaultApi", routeTemplate: "api/{tenancy}/{controller}", defaults: null, constraints: null, handler: AuthenticationHandler);
```

Also what URI are you requesting to get the 404 error? What is tenancy?

Comment: I have a doubt that something else is going wrong somewhere. I would investigate today and post an update.